# Use textbox in gridview bound field in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview which I used to display tabular data. 
I want the users to edit the field values and save it. 
Is there any way to add a textbox in place of bound field. 
This is my gridview.

```
   <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
Height="186px" Width="325px">
          <Columns>       
          </Columns>
  </asp:GridView>
```

This is the code behind which populate the GridView

```
    public List<DataControlField> columns = new List<DataControlField>();
    public object DataSource { get; set; }

    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            BoundField bf = new BoundField() ; 
            bf.HeaderText = "LastName"  ; 
            bf.DataField = "LastName";

            columns.Add(bf);
        }

        foreach (DataControlField col in columns)
        {
            GridView1.Columns.Add(col);
        } 


    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Data> lastN = new List<Data>() ; 
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 50; i++ )
        {
            lastN.Add(new Data(i.ToString())); 
        }
        GridView1.DataSource = lastN;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: any particular reason why you are creating columns at code-behind?

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest you to try listview, it allows you to edit the dynamic data, such as the content in textbox

Comment: Is it possible to auto-save the data in listview as you type ? 
I want to create an excel like grid which enables to auto-save.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a GridView with EditTemplates. You can refer to this [example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37207/Editable-Gridview-with-Textbox-CheckBox-Radio-Butt) for that.

It is possible to edit all rows of a GridView at the same time. Refer to this [example](http://highoncoding.com/Articles/219_GridView_All_Rows_in_Edit_Mode.aspx).

You can optionally use Telerik's ASP.NET Data Grid that you can configure to work like excel using this [example](http://blogs.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/posts/13-07-30/create-excel-asp-net-grid).

Comment: this is not the way we answer at  SO. What you have given is only links to third party sites. This should be a comment